# How to pass command line arguments to R script as key value pair

Tags: command-line-arguments, rscript

I want to pass command line arguments to Rscript as key-value pair instead of values.

Currently I am calling as below

```
Rscript myrscript.R 10 20
```

I would like to call something as below

```
Rscript myrscript.R a=10 b=20
```

And finally how can read these arguments in R script using key's ?

Comment: Did you solve this yet? I am looking to do a similar thing